# P4300 G2 SAN FAN Header Connections

Tags: storage-area-network, hp, hp-proliant, hardware

I've recently had to replace the System Board on my P4300 G2 SAN due to a failure to find a boot drive. Unfortunately after replacing this it won't boot past the POST screen, it identifies that there is a fan missing and that "The Fan Solution is insufficient".

There are 6 headers and only 4 connections. I can't take it's partner in the pair out to look at it's connections as it's running our production systems.

I've tried the following permutations (see table Below) and I've identified that the required connections are 1,2,3,5 and 6. The only header that appears to be ignored is 4.

I've contacted HP already (via the system board replacement) but they don't seem to understand the problem, I'm getting an engineer out ASAP but ideally I'd like to solve this sooner than that so that if there is another underlying problem he can bring the right kit with him.

Permutations attempted to identify required headers

1,2,3,4 (error 1611 Fan 5, error 1611 6 missing)

1,2,5,6 (error 1611 Fan 3 missing)

1,2,3,5 (error 1611 Fan 6 missing)

1,3,5,6 (error 1611 Fan 2 missing)

2,3,5,6 (error 1611 Fan 1 missing)

Comment: Call HP, seriously.

Comment: What jumpers did you change? I am having the same issue with an replacement motherboard on an X1600 (based on DL180 G6 - similar to the P4300).

Comment: For my system board (which I think uses the identical system board to the X1600) I had to remove all the jumpers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the jumper settings match from the old board to the new? This general series of devices from HP sometimes share a systemboard and the only difference in displayed model was a jumper. It also determined how many fans it required to have connected.

We learned the hard way in a datacenter that just started playing with the DL160 G6, then known to us as the SE316M1. We had few spares on site and had to overnight the faulty systemboard back once replaced, and we stupidly didn't check that first.

Comment: Yep, this was it, however the engineer from HP is still here trying to find out what is causing it to spontaneously reboot. As it stands, we're running on reduced redundancy and as a result I am not sleeping well at night. 1 node down 1 node up is not a good situation to be in...

Answer (score 4):

You are under support. Call HP to ask. The unit only uses 4 fans. There's also a slight chance that there's another system board problem. Make sure that the tech brings one just in case.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer, but it's a long and somewhat relevant comment:

We were building up an HP DL380 with Xenserver and 4 or 5 Windows VMS. The basic install and pre-site config was done (not my area). The CDROM drive wouldn't work due to a broken connector onboard, and we decided this wasn't good enough to send to the customer even though it was unlikely they'd use the CDROM drive, so we escalated it to HP and replaced the system board. The new board kept reporting that we didn't have enough fans, despite us not having changed anything else.  The new 5400 series Xeons didn't need the second fan kit, so it was discontinued, and this meant HP could no longer even supply us the extra fan kit.

They insisted they'd replaced the right systemboard model, but ended up (after a lot of emails and phone calls) coming out to replace the front controller board as well. That fixed the problem, but they shorted something on the systemboard which blew up the keyboard and ethernet controllers. Oh, and the RAID array.

We ended up with a complete replacement unit, and having to reinstall the entire system from the ground up.

My point? Back your data up now. :)